# Moving Files from one S3 bucket to another which are updated in last two days

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, etl

I am in process to build a data pipeline which loads the data from s3 to Amazon redshift, I have a s3 bucket with layered folder structure, e.g

```
Amazon S3>bucket-name/10849813427/2.0/2018/08/16/10958160321
```

and my files are placed in the last directory (e.g. 10958160321).

I have multiple folders like this in my S3 bucket(bucket-name), now from all these folders in this S3 bucket I want to copy files having "last_modified_date" in last two days in another S3 bucket. I will process these files using my ETL job and load data in Redshift.

Is there a way to filter out files while copying to another bucket or another folder inside the same bucket?

Thanks

Comment: As per your below comment are you able to post your boto3 solution or accept the below answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot modify any object with S3. If you want to change an existing object you need to delete the existing one and overwrite with the new object. This includes rename and its metadata.

**S3 Metadata:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

You can specify or loop multiple dates to find for respective dates.

```
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/2018/ --recursive | grep $DATE
```

With regards to scalability, if you have more objects you will run into timing issue in collecting the list of object with their modified date.

**S3 Inventory:**

If a 24-hour delay is acceptable to collect the list of objects, you can use S3 inventory to list the objects with their created date.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html

An inventory will be delivered to an s3 bucket and you can trigger a lambda, read the contents and move the object to the right location.

**S3 Copy:**

You can use cli/lambda to copy between buckets or within the same bucket.

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket1/folder1  s3://bucket1/folder2  --recursive
aws s3 mv s3://bucket1/folder1  s3://bucket1/folder1  --recursive
```

**EDIT1:**

Actual script for a simple loop through to copy from source to destination

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                  
aws s3api list-objects --bucket "bucket-name" --prefix "prefix/foldername" --query "Contents[?LastModified>='2018-10-02'].{Key: Key}" --profile production | tr '\n' ' ' | jq -c '.[].Key' | while read i; do                                         
    aws s3 mv s3://sourbucket/$i s3://destinationbucket/                                                            
done
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this gives me a lot to browse further, what I am looking for is if I can pass one filter while copying the files onto another bucket or folder, as mentioned in your last example, can I do something like:
aws s3 mv s3://bucket1/folder1  s3://bucket1/folder2  --recursive --query 'Contents[?LastModified>=`'2018-09-29'`]
Also I need to give date dynamically, can I use something like sysdate, instead hard coding the date('2018-09-29')!

Comment: Added a single script and made you lazier :) . Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, it is really helpful, but due to some reason I did end up using Python(boto3) for the task :), I am able to find the keys for this condition.

Comment: check the version of your awscli first. Worked after upgrading awscli 1.11.47 -> 1.16.220

Comment: Thanks. Only needed to add `-r` to the last `jq` command and it worked for me on awscli 1.16

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to down the file from a source bucket, stage it, then upload it to a target bucket

```
s3_client.download_file(key,download_path)

s3_client.upload_file(Bucket='destination-bucket',
filename=filename,
Key=key)
```